# React Native Functional Components & React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello guys I'm trying to fetch XML data and insert it into an array called `meterDataList`
using the react hooks, and I get this error thrown in the console

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result['counter']['counternumber']')]
```

```
function getReadingOrder(Emp_Number,{navigation}){
const [meterDataList,setArray] = useState([]);
fetch('http://localhost/gecol/partner/api.php?emp_number='+`${Emp_Number}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => { var xml2js = require('xml2js');

            var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
            parser.parseString(data, function(err,result){          
            // meterDataList.push([{servicePoint:222, counternumber:result['counter']['counternumber']}])
            setArray(meterDataList => [meterDataList,{servicePoint:222, counternumber:result['counter']['counternumber']}])
      })
    })
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);
    console.log(meterDataList);
    return (  
      
      <SafeAreaProvider >
        <View style={ReaderHome.Accordion}>
          {meterDataList.map((meter, i) => (
          <ListItem.Accordion 
            content={
              <>
              <Avatar size={64} icon={{ name: 'home', type: 'AntDesign' }} containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#1f95c0' }}/>
              <ListItem.Content>
                <ListItem.Title style={{left:10}}><Text style={ReaderHome.ConsumerName}>{meter.consumer}</Text></ListItem.Title>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{left:10}}><Text style={ReaderHome.ServiceNumber}>{meter.servicePoint}</Text></ListItem.Subtitle>
                </ListItem.Content>
              </>
            }
            isExpanded={expanded}
            onPress={() => {
              setExpanded(!expanded);
            }}
              >
              <ListItem key={i} onPress={alert(meter.lastdate)} bottomDivider>
                <Avatar title={''} source={''} />
                  <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title>{meter.currentread}</ListItem.Title>
                    <ListItem.Subtitle>meter.lastread</ListItem.Subtitle>
                  </ListItem.Content>
                  <ListItem.Chevron />
              </ListItem>
          </ListItem.Accordion>))}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>);
      
  }
```